# Can connect to any website except youtube.com - Server not found

Tags: networking, wireless, server, youtube

Good evening,

I've recently installed Ubuntu 16.04.
I setup a wireless connection and it works flawlessly on any website except youtube.com.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdfu8.png)

I've pinged it and it seems like there aren't any problems.

I've tried accessing youtube.com with both chromium and firefox to no avail.

Clearing cache via `Sandwich > More tools > Clear browsing data > Obliterate everything from the beginning of time` (Chromium)
and `Sandwich > Preferences > Advanced > Network > Cached Web Content > Clear Now` (Firefox) doesn't work either.

Using wget results in (link to picture below) but I don't seem to get what's wrong.

Finally, I've tried the cached version of Google. This gets me to the homepage, however if I click any video or search anything the Server not found error comes back

*I have more pictures here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/posWe.jpg but I cannot post more than 2 links or embed pictures.*

Some unspecific information if they might be of help:
Laptop: Dell Latittude E4200 running ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Router: TP-Link TL-WR841N

Comment: What happen when you access youtube.com using other device connected to the same wireless network?

Comment: @Yaron Works as it should, however I should add my other device is connected via ethernet cable and runs windows.

Comment: what happened when you try to connect to the following youtube ip: `172.217.22.14` ?

Comment: Note: running wget using the `youtube` ip which appear in your image (wget 129.143.66.34) resolved with a gzipped index.html file.

Comment: Did you try with `https`? Did you try to use another DNS server (e.g. 8.8.8.8)?

Comment: So if I understood you correctly, I ran wget with 172.217.22.14 http://imgur.com/a/riWN9 and tried connecting again. Still did not work

Comment: @Takkat So I checked my DNS first to see what I've used with `nmcli device show name` and it seems to be `192.167.0.1`. But how would I go about changing it? Connecting to `https://youtube.com` won't work either.

Answer (score 0):

http://youtube.com is being redirected to http://**www**.youtube.com, which on your machine seems to not resolve on DNS.

Do you have any DNS blocking services running our your router?